# Инъекция бинов в List и тестирование

Tags: java, spring, юнит-тесты, dependency-injection, bean

Всем добрый день. У меня есть класс:

```
@Component
public class A {

    @Autowired
    private List<B> list; 
   
}
```

Где B - это интерфейс с другого проекта (зависимости в pom прописаны).
И есть тесты для этого класса:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = {1.class, 2.class, 3.class, 4.class, A.class})
@ImportAutoConfiguration(RefreshAutoConfiguration.class) - необходим из-за скоупа бинов
public class ATest {
    @Autowired
    private A a;
}
```

где 1,2,3,4 - это классы с другого проекта реализующие интерфейс B.
Проблема в том, что 1,2,3,4 бины в контексте теста есть, но List - не заполняется ими.

Answer (score 0):

Вариант следующий

```
@Component
@Profile("test")
public class Test1 implenets B{
}
```

Сам же тест будет выгладить следующий образом

```
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfile("test")
public class ATest {
    @Autowired
    private A a;
}
```